# How to find conditional extreme with parameter in condition?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to find conditional extreme of next function with parameter in condition?

$$
f(x,y) = x+y, \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{y^2} = \frac{1}{a^2}, a > 0
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Lagrange multipliers
Let $k$ be a real parameter. Write a linear combination of the function and the constraint
$$f(x,y,k)=x+y+k\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$
and set to zero the three partial derivatives
$$\frac{2 k}{x^3}+1=0;\;\frac{2 k}{y^3}+1=0;\;\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}=0$$
From the first we get $k= -\dfrac{x^3}{2}$ from the second $k= -\dfrac{y^3}{2}$

Therefore  $-\dfrac{x^3}{2}=-\dfrac{y^3}{2}$ that means $x=y$

Plug this in the third equation
$$-\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$
simplify
$$\frac{2}{x^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}\rightarrow x^2=2a^2$$
thus $x=\pm a\sqrt{2};\;y=\pm a\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$ 1 - \frac{2k}{x^3} $$ same for partial derivative for y?